# nginx can't listen on port 80

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to set nginx with gunicorn but I keep getting the "Welcome to nginx!" page. I am able to successfully listen to other ports (like 8080) but port 80 does not work at all.

```
server { 
listen          80;
server_name     host.ca www.host.ca;
access_log      /var/log/nginx/example2.log;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;

}
```

}

I'm running the server as root.
I can't seem to see anything running in port 80.

Comment: What does `netstat -nlp | grep 80` return?

Comment: I was using centos-6. it doesn't have site-enabled etc. I have to remove server entry /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and add nginx.conf in same directory.

Answer (score 3):

## Diagnosing the Problem

Make sure to check your logs (likely `/var/log/nginx` or some variant).

Check to see what might be hogging port 80

```
netstat -nlp | grep 80
```

## Sites-enabled, port hogging

Then, make sure you have the Django site enabled in `sites-enabled`. Delete any old symlinks if you created one first.

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/django /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django
```

Double check your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to make sure it's loading sites-enabled and not loading some other default.

```
http {
  ...
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

After you do all this, shut down and restart the nginx service.

Either `service nginx restart` or `service nginx stop && service nginx start`

Comment: netstat -nlp |grep 80 tells me that nginx is listening at port 80 (when I don't set it to port 80). 0.0.0.0:80. Is that normal?

Comment: Sounds like another configuration is taking precedence over the one you have set up. Look in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf for culprits, as well as extraneous sites in sites-enabled.

Comment: Only "default" existed. There are no other ports being listened to on nginx.conf just port 80..

Comment: I fixed the extraneous culprit so there are now officially no other nginx.conf listening to port 80. I still can't get past the welcome screen..

Comment: Have you restarted too? `service nginx restart`